# Time Travel error when updating Access Control on BigQuery dataset

Tags: google-bigquery

We use python to programmatically grant authorized view / routine access to a large number of views to various datasets.

However since this week we have been receiving the following error :
**Dataset time travel window can only be modified once in 1 hours. The previous change happened 0 hours ago**

This is preventing our current deployment process.

And so far we have not been able to find a work around to resolve this error. Note that we do not touch the time travel configurations at all as a part of our process.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue with the BigQuery API.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Google have said that they will be rolling back the breaking change to restore functionality within the day

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).